# SSD in enclosure does not mount on older MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, memory, flash-memory

I bought a Crucial SSD compatible with my MacBook Pro (late 2007) and an enclosure. To my frustration, it would not mount and I think the hardware may be defective.

Sometimes, I get it to mount and the drive will stay visible on the desktop. At other times, the LED on the drive will briefly flash but nothing would appear.

How can I get my Mac to recognize this new hard drive?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is, make sure that your SSD has adequate power.

Some USB cables come with two USB plugs at one end.

The second and thinner part of the cable is needed for power supply.

So plug in both ends one in each USB port of the computer and then it should supply enough power.

Alternatively, and this made for a more reliable power supply, one can use any USB device that supplies power. In this case an iPhone charger attached to the second USB end (power-only) did the trick.